# Why should I use separate initialization and clean up methods instead of putting logic in the constructor and destructor for engine components?

Tags: architecture, software-engineering

I'm working on my own game engine, and I am currently designing my managers. I've read that for memory management, using `Init()` and `CleanUp()` functions are better then using constructors and destructors.

I have been looking for C++ code examples, to see how those functions work and how I can implement them into my engine. How does `Init()` and `CleanUp()` work, and how can I implement them into my engine?

Comment: Se http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/

Comment: For C++, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786853/why-use-an-initialization-method-instead-of-a-constructor
Main reasons to use Init() are 1) Prevent exceptions and crashes in the constructor with helper functions 2) Being able to use virtual methods from the derived class 3) Circumvent circular dependencies 4) as private method to avoid code duplication

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty simple, actually:

Instead of having a Constructor which does your setup,

```
// c-family pseudo-code
public class Thing {
    public Thing (a, b, c, d) { this.x = a; this.y = b; /* ... */ }
}
```

...have your constructor do little or nothing at all, and write a method called `.init` or `.initialize`, which would do what your constructor would normally do.

```
public class Thing {
    public Thing () {}
    public void initialize (a, b, c, d) {
        this.x = a; /*...*/
    }
}
```

So now instead of just going like:

```
Thing thing = new Thing(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

You can go:

```
Thing thing = new Thing();

thing.doSomething();
thing.bind_events(evt_1, evt_2);
thing.initialize(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

The benefit there is that you can now use dependency-injection/inversion-of-control more-easily in your systems.

Instead of saying

```
public class Soldier {
    private Weapon weapon;

    public Soldier (name, x, y) {
        this.weapon = new Weapon();
    }
}
```

You can build the soldier, give him an equip method, where you *hand* him a weapon, and THEN call all of the rest of the constructor functions.

So now, instead of subclassing enemies where one soldier has a pistol and another has a rifle and another has a shotgun, and that's the only difference, you can just say:

```
Soldier soldier1 = new Soldier(),
        soldier2 = new Soldier(),
        soldier3 = new Soldier();

soldier1.equip(new Pistol());
soldier2.equip(new Rifle());
soldier3.equip(new Shotgun());

soldier1.initialize("Bob",  32,  48);
soldier2.initialize("Doug", 57, 200);
soldier3.initialize("Mike", 92,  30);
```

Same deal with destruction.  If you have special needs (removing event listeners, removing instances from arrays/whatever structures you're working with, etc), you would then manually call them, so that you know exactly when and where in the program that was happening.

**EDIT**

---

As Kryotan has pointed out, below, this answers the original post's **"How"**, but doesn't really do a good job of a "Why".

As you can probably see in the answer above, there might not be much of a difference between:

```
var myObj = new Object();
myObj.setPrecondition(1);
myObj.setOtherPrecondition(2);
myObj.init();
```

and writing

```
var myObj = new Object(1,2);
```

while just having a larger constructor function.
There is an argument to be made for objects which have 15 or 20 pre-conditions, which would make a constructor very, very hard to work with, and it would make things easier to see and remember, by pulling those things out into the interface, so that you can see how the instantiation works, one level higher.

Optional-configuration of objects is a natural extension to this; optionally setting values on the interface, before making the object run.
JS has some great shortcuts for this idea, which just seem out of place in stronger-typed c-like languages.

That said, chances are, if you're dealing with an argument list that long in your constructor, that your object is too big and does too much, as is.  Again, this is a personal-preference thing, and there are exceptions far and wide, but if you're passing 20 things into an object, chances are good that you could find a way to make that object do less, by making smaller objects.

A more-pertinent reason, and one which is widely-applicable would be that the initialization of an object relies on asynchronous data, which you don't have, currently.

You know that you need the object, so you're going to create it anyway, but in order to have it function properly, it needs data from the server, or from another file which it now needs to load.

Again, whether you're passing the needed data into a gigantic init, or building out an interface isn't really important to the concept, so much as it's important to the interface of your object, and the design of your system...

But in terms of building the object, you might do something like this:

```
var obj_w_async_dependencies = new Object();
async_loader.load(obj_w_async_dependencies.async_data, obj_w_async_dependencies);
```

`async_loader` might get passed a filename, or a resource name or whatever, load that resource -- maybe it loads sound files, or image data, or maybe it loads saved character stats...

...and then it would feed that data back into `obj_w_async_dependencies.init(result);`.

This sort of dynamic is found frequently in web-apps.
Not necessarily in an object's construction, for higher-level applications: for example, galleries might load and initialize right away, and then display photos as they stream in -- that's not really an async-initialization, but where it's seen more frequently would be in JavaScript libraries.

One module might depend on another, and so the initialization of that module might be deferred until the loading of the dependants is complete.

In terms of game-specific instances of this, consider an actual `Game` class.

Why can't we call `.start` or `.run` in the constructor?
Resources need to be loaded -- the rest of everything has pretty much been defined and is good to go, but if we try running the game without a database-connection, or without textures or models or sounds or levels, it's not going to be a particularly interesting game...

...so what, then is the difference between what we see of a typical `Game`, except that we give its "go ahead" method a name which is more interesting than `.init` (or conversely, break the initialization even further apart, to separate loading, setting up the things which have been loaded, and running the program when everything has been set up).

Comment: "*you would then manually call them, so that you know exactly when and where in the program that was happening.*" The only time in C++ where a destructor would be implicitly called is for a stack object (or global). Heap allocated objects require explicit destruction. So it's always clear when the object is being deallocated.

Comment: It's not exactly accurate to say that you need this separate method to enable the injection of different weapon types, or that this is the only way to avoid proliferation of subclasses. You can pass the weapon instances in via the constructor! So it's a -1 from me as this is not a compelling use case.

Comment: -1 From me as well, for pretty much the same reasons as Kylotan. You don't make a very compelling argument, all this could have been done with constructors.

Comment: Yes, it could be accomplished with constructors and destructors. He asked for use-cases of a technique and why and how, rather than how they work or why they do.  Having a component-based system where you have setter/binding methods, versus constructor-passed parameters for DI really all comes down to how you want to build your interface. But if your object requires 20 IOC components, do you want to put ALL of them into your constructor?  Can you?  Of course you can.  Should you?  Maybe, maybe not.  If you choose *not* to, then do you need a `.init`, maybe not, but likely. Ergo, valid case.

Comment: Technically he asked *why* you'd use a method like this, and this answer basically begs the question because it assumes you already want to do it this way. It also misses the fact that the original question is really about a single `Init` function rather than a series of setup functions, ie. why would you have all your setup in a single function if that function is not the constructor?

Comment: @Kylotan I actually edited the title of the question to ask why.  The OP only asked "how".  I extended the question to include the "why" as the "how" is trivial to anybody who knows anything about programming ("Just move the logic you would have into the ctor into a separate function and call it") and the "why" is more interesting/general.

Comment: @Kylotan, I agree. The reason the answer is worded in such a way is simply because it's based on the assumption you're already doing it that way, but have no idea why... Such was sort of the nature of the OP ("I read these articles that said I should, but didn't tell me anything else"). So these are potential blanks filled in, from that standpoint.  Other real-world cases?  As a JavaScript dev in my other life, async is certainly a time where if you're waiting on promises/futures, you want to hold off on running your large `.init`. In the game world, this might be async I/O or loading.

Comment: @Kylotan, in these situations, having a monolithic `.init` method might be plausible, if your object *MUST* already be instantiated for some predetermined reason, but at least part of its setup (which would have been covered in the monolithic constructor in a 100% procedural environment), needs to be deferred until the loading of a resource, or until an instruction from a socket, or data is retrieved from somewhere remote, has to happen.  The alternative would be to break the object into two pieces, do the sync stuff in one, and the async in the other, but private state...

Comment: ...or management of construction of these objects might not always be in your control, or might otherwise go against the intent/design of the system.

Comment: So is this a "every component/entity/class/etc in every system in every engine you ever build must have an explicit `.init()`"? Not remotely.  It's: "Here's a situation where you might consider using one".  Quickest example of when that might be: you've created `Soldier soldier = new Soldier();` because you know you need him, but you need the server's permission to add him -- the server is expected to respond with coordinates for the new enemy, because you're doing networking using the right paradigms. When the future coordinates are given, the soldier has them added, is initialized and added.

Comment: Sure. The example in your last comment is more relevant than the example currently in the answer. The main reason to split constructor and initialisation is because of some temporal dependency in the middle, but that's not currently in your answer.

Comment: @Kylotan I extended my answer to more-aptly cover the content of the edited OP, rather than just the content of the original original, including comparison to the concept of the `Game` class (with a `.load` and `.init` or whatever they may be called).  Hope that makes things a little more practical in terms of where this technique might see high-level use.

Comment: @Norguard: certainly. Changed my vote accordingly!

Answer (score 17):

Whatever you read that said Init and CleanUp is better, should have also told you why. Articles that don't justify their claims are not worth reading.

Having separate initialisation and shutdown functions can make it easier to set up and destroy systems because you can choose what order to call them in, whereas constructors get called exactly when the object is created and destructors called when the object is destroyed. When you have complex dependencies between 2 objects you often need them both to exist before they set themselves up - but often this is a sign of poor design elsewhere.

Some languages don't have destructors that you can rely on, since reference counting and garbage collection make it harder to know when the object will be destroyed. In these languages you almost always need a shutdown/cleanup method, and some like to add the init method for symmetry.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm mainly looking for examples, since the article didn't have them. I apologize if my question was unclear about that, but I have edited it now.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best reason is : to allow pooling.
if you have Init and CleanUp, you can, when an object is killed, just call CleanUp, and push the object onto a stack of object of the same type : a 'pool'.
Then, whenever you need a new object, you can pop one object from the pool OR if the pool is empty -too bad- you have to create a new one. Then you call Init on this object.
A good strategy is to pre-fill the pool before the game begins with a 'good' number of objects, so you never have to create any pooled object during the game.
If, on the the other hand, you use 'new', and just stop referencing an object when it is of no use to you, you create garbage that must be recollected at some time.
This recollection is especially a bad thing for single-threaded languages like Javascript, where the garbage collector stops all the code when it evaluates it needs to recollects the memory of the objects no longer in use. The game hangs during a few milliseconds, and playing experience is spoiled.
- You allready understood - : if you pool all your objects, no recollection happens, hence no more random slow-down.

It is also much faster to call init on an object coming from the pool than to allocate memory + init a new object.
But the speed improvement has less importance, since quite often object creation is not a performance bottleneck... With a few exceptions, like frantic games, particle engines, or physic engine using intensively 2D/3d vectors for their computations. Here both speed and garbage creation are greatly improved by using a pool.

Rq : you might not need to have a CleanUp method for your pooled objects if the Init() resets everything.

Edit : replying to this post motivated me to finalize a little article i made about pooling *in Javascript*.
You can find it here if you're interested :
[http://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/](http://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/no-more-garbage-pooling-objects-built-with-constructor-functions/)

Comment: -1: You don't need to do this just to have a pool of objects. You can do that by just separating allocation from construction via placement new and deallocation from deletion by an explicit destructor call. So this is not a valid reason to separate constructors/destructors from some initializer method.

Comment: placement new is C++ specific, and a bit esoteric as well.

Comment: +1 it may be possible to do this in other way in c+. But not in other languages... and this is probably only reason why I would use Init method on gameobjects.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas : i think you're overreacting. The fact that there are other ways to do pooling (you mention a complex one, specific to C++) does not invalidate the fact that using a separate Init is a nice and simple way to implement pooling in many languages. my preferences goes, on GameDev, to more generic answers.

Comment: @VincentPiel: How is using placement new and such "complex" in C++? Also, if you're working in a GC language, odds are good that objects will contain GC-based objects. So will they also have to poll each of them? Thus, creating a new object will involve getting a bunch of new objects from pools.

Comment: @Kylotan: Placement new is far less "esoteric" than the notion of having pointers to objects that are, according to the language, alive yet cannot be used. It's only "esoteric" to those C++ programmers raised in more of a C-with-classes style of C++. For more modern C++ programmers who actually follow the model of the language, placement new is standard practice and init/deinit is considered non-standard and dangerous.

Comment: Using Init() worked like a charm for me (+5fps) in my modest experiments of Javascript. I do not doubt your way of pooling in C++ is interesting. Now that the position of everyone is understood, i suggest we carry on (i will).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is reversed... Historically speaking, the more pertinent question is:

**Why *is* [construction + intialisation conflated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), i.e. why *don't* we do these steps separately? Surely this goes against [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)?**

For C++, [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)'s intent is that resource acquisition and release be tied directly to object lifetime, in the hopes that this will assure resource release. Does it? Partly. It is 100% fulfilled in the context of stack-based / automatic variables, where leaving the associated scope automatically calls destructors / releases these variables (hence the qualifier `automatic`). However for heap variables, this very useful pattern sadly breaks down, since you are still forced to explicitly call `delete` in order to run the destructor, and if you forget to do so you will still be bitten by what RAII attempts to solve; in context of heap-allocated variables, then, C++ provides limited benefit over C (`delete` vs `free()`) while conflating construction with initialisation, which negatively impacts in terms of the following:

- [Resource Acquisition should not equate to Initialisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) because this does not prevents explicit call ordering especially as this applies to [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)
- RAII implies that zeroing / deinitialisation of objects requires destruction + reconstruction, which can be costly in games where [object pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) is favoured

Building an object system for games / simulations in C is strongly recommended in that it will shed a great deal of light on the limitations of RAII and other such OO-centric patterns through a deeper understanding of the assumptions that C++ and later classical OO languages make (remember that C++ started out as a an OO system built in C).